# How to set up ASIC properly?

Tags: asic

Okay so butterfly labs has these [ASIC chips](https://products.butterflylabs.com/homepage-subproducts/65nm-asic-bitcoin-mining-chip.html) available yet I am very confused on how to implement these. I have never seen these type of things and googling has gotten me nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation to these chips has not been released yet, as you can see on the page:

> Reference documentation:  Butterfly Labs is releasing it's PCB schematics & MCU code to open source.  Links to this documentation will follow shortly.

Be aware that by ordering these you are not purchasing a finished product, you are just purchasing the chips to build one.

Comment: @Griffin: There are (will be) companies that will take the chips from you and assemble them into a board for you. [TerraHash](https://terrahash.com/?product=4-5-ghsec-module) for example.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Also it says 100. Does that mean you get 100 at 4.5 GHz each or 100 that add up to 4.5GHz?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm talking about the product from butterfly labs

Comment: 100 is the minimum order. It has nothing to do with the chip's specifications.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand that however I'm wondering is each chip 4.5GHz or are they all combined 4.5GHz

Comment: Neither. The chips do not run at 4.5GHz and speeds do not add up (100 cars going 50 miles per hour don't "add up" to 5,000 miles per hour). However, each chip is capable of doing hashes at a rate of 4.5GH/s, and rates at which work is done *do* add up.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That was my fault adding the z in there sorry.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But does each one do 4GH/s or do all 100 add up to 4GH/s

Comment: @Griffin Each chip is capable of doing hashes at a rate of 4.5GH/s.